# Oracle pivot rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables:

```
TABLE1
------
id name
1  n1
2  n2


TABLE2
------
id tipo valor
1  t1   v1
1  t2   v2
2  t1   v1
2  t2   v5
2  t3   v3
```

And I'm trying to get:

```
id name t1 t2 t3
1  n1   v1 v2 -
2  n2   v1 v5 v3
```

Is it possible? I have been looking examples but still I don't get nothing clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `PIVOT` Clause

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t1.*, t2.tipo, t2.valor 
          FROM table1 t1 
          JOIN table2 t2 
            ON t2.id = t1.id)
 PIVOT 
 (
  MAX(valor) FOR tipo IN ( 't1' AS "t1", 't2' AS "t2", 't3' AS "t3" )
 )
```

but this is static, eg. needs to be updated as different values for `tipo` column is added. In order to make it dynamic, you can create a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Cols RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767); 
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);      
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||tipo||''' AS "'||tipo||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY tipo )  
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM table2 );

  v_sql := 'SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT t1.*, t2.tipo, t2.valor 
                      FROM table1 t1 
                      JOIN table2 t2 
                        ON t2.id = t1.id)
             PIVOT 
             (
              MAX(valor) FOR tipo IN ( '|| v_cols ||' )
             )';   

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call by using

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Pivoted_Cols;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL developer's console.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43555d39ce6911014fdb1761b31e3eb9)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
    max(case when t2.typo = 't1' then t2.valor end) as t1,
    max(case when t2.typo = 't2' then t2.valor end) as t2,
    max(case when t2.typo = 't3' then t2.valor end) as t3
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

This returns `null` values for `typo`s that do not exist. If you want `'-'` instead, you can surround the conditional aggregates with `coalesce()`, like so:

```
    coalesce(max(case when t2.typo = 't1' then t2.valor end), '-') as t1
```